# Having an issue with the month of February showing as a valid date

Tags: java

So I been working on this program and I have gotten some dates to work out fine but when I input the month of February with a future year it shows that its invalid when it shouldn't be. 
For the sake of this program days in February are just 1-28.
Can anyone help me catch my mistake?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    public class FutureDate {
     public static void main (String args[]){

  int inputMonth;
  int inputDate;
  int inputYear;
  final int currentMonth = 10;
  final int currentDate = 24;
  final int currentYear = 2013;
  final int numberOfDays = 31; 

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a month in format - mm: ");
  inputMonth = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter a day in format - dd: ");
  inputDate= keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter a year in format - yyyy: ");
  inputYear = keyboard.nextInt();


  if (inputYear < currentYear)
  System.out.println("Invalid Date");

  else if (inputYear >= currentYear)


  {

     if (inputMonth >= 1 && inputMonth <=12){        

        if ((inputMonth == 4 || inputMonth == 6 || inputMonth == 9 || inputMonth == 11) && (inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 30))
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else if (inputMonth > currentMonth && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <=30)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else if (inputMonth == currentMonth && inputDate > currentDate && inputDate <=30)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else

        System.out.println("Invalid Date");
        }

     else if (inputMonth == 2 && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 28){
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        if (inputMonth > currentMonth && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <=28)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else if (inputMonth == currentMonth && inputDate > currentDate && inputDate<=28)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");
        } 

      else if (inputMonth == 1 || inputMonth == 3 || inputMonth == 5 || inputMonth == 7 || inputMonth ==10 || inputMonth == 12 && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 31){

        if (inputMonth > currentMonth && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <=31)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else if (inputMonth == currentMonth && inputDate > currentDate && inputDate <=31)
        System.out.println("Valid Date");

        else
        System.out.println("Invalid Date");

     }

      else           
      System.out.println ("Invalid Date");

        }

  }

  }
```

Comment: always surround your else/if blocks with { } if you're going to do it some places and not others.  Makes it a PITA to read otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your first if clause checks if it's between January and December(Which february is), so it goes into that if clause instead of the second one.

Move your second if before the first

Answer (score 1):

1. **ALWAYS** use curly braces for single-line **if**-s and **else**-s.
2. Let's look at your first **if**

   ```
   // 1.
   if (inputMonth >= 1 && inputMonth <=12){        
   // 2.
   if ((inputMonth == 4 || inputMonth == 6 || inputMonth == 9 || inputMonth == 11) && (inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 30))
   System.out.println("Valid Date");
   // 3.
   else if (inputMonth > currentMonth && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <=30)
   System.out.println("Valid Date");
   // 4.
   else if (inputMonth == currentMonth && inputDate > currentDate && inputDate <=30)
   System.out.println("Valid Date");
   // 5.
   else

   System.out.println("Invalid Date");
   }
   ```

   - // 1 is true, so we enter.
   - // 2 is false; proceed
   - // 3 is false; proceed
   - // 4 is false; proceed

and now we're at // 5, which prints out "invalid date".

Gotta fix up your logic.